# AngularJS $http REST call returns null data

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, http, angularjs-service

I have a REST service that returns a JSON object. I am trying to make the authentication but it responses with empty data.

I did notice that the call is asychronous and when the user is pressing the login button it makes the call before getting the username and password. So I decided to use the $q constructor in order to fix it, but the problem consists, it still returns null data.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

*factory*

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.factory('User', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

    return {
    login: function(username, password) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/CashInRestServices_war/rest/user/login', {username: username, password: password})
            .then (function(data, status, headers, config){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }, function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject(data);
            })
        return deferred.promise;
        }   
    }
}])
```

*controller*

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {

    $scope.username = "viewer";
    $scope.password = "viewer";

    $scope.login = function() {
        User.login($scope.username ,$scope.password)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log("success!");
                $scope.status = response.status;
                $scope.data = response.data;
                $scope.username = response.username;
                alert("Success!!!    " + JSON.stringify({data: response.data}));
        }, function (response) { 
                $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
                $scope.status = response.status;
                console.log("Error!!!");
                alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: response.data}));
        })
    };
}])
```

*****EDIT*****

I did change the code a little bit. I think the problem was how the $http was written.

*factory*

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.factory('User', ['$http', function($http) {
return {
    login: function(username, password) {
return $http({method:'post', url: 'http://localhost:8080/CashInRestServices_war/rest/user/login', username: username, password: password})
        }   
    }
}])
```

It did somehow worked but it returns loginCheck:false. It seems that it does not recognize the correct username and password.

```
response = Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

log:

```
Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}config: Objectheaders: Objectmethod: 

"POST"paramSerializer: (b)password: "viewer"transformRequest: Array[1]transformResponse: Array[1]url: "http://localhost:8080/CashInRestServices_war/rest/user/login"username: "viewer"__proto__: Objectdata: ObjectloginCheck: false__proto__: 

Objectheaders: (c)arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 1name: ""prototype: Objectconstructor: (c)__proto__: Object__proto__: ()<function scope>ClosureClosureGlobal: Windowstatus: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: __lookupSetter__()

constructor: Object()hasOwnProperty: hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: toLocaleString()toString: toString()valueOf: valueOf()get __proto__: get __proto__()set __proto__: set __proto__()
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your service? You're sure that you're actually hitting the service? Does it log `console.log("success!")` or `console.log("Error!!!")`?

Comment: Yes, I did. When i did put the whole code into the controller the call was successful and returned the user's username. Now using factory it logs console.log("Error!!!")

Comment: So if you put your `$http.post` inside you controller, everything works just fine?

Comment: can you show result of console.log("Error!!!", response);

Comment: @Detilium yes, but I cannot use a button there unfortunately.

Comment: Then it has to do with your connection between the controller and the service i guess? Cold you please try using a callback? Like so: `User.login($scope.username ,$scope.password, function(data, doSomething()))` where `doSomething()` = whatever you do in your `.then`? (I don't know if this would do any difference?)

Comment: @benek it returns this: response = Object {data: null, status: 0, config: Object, statusText: ""

Comment: So your service is returning null. Changing on promises and the way you call them won't change anything. Check the API you are calling. You should call it differently. Or maybe status:0 is considered as ok ? ...

Comment: @benek I edited my code, I changed the $http form. It did manage to do a connection but it came back with a loginCheck:false respone, but the password is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The login function was causing the problem `$scope.login = function()` so I used the $event object.

*html*

```
<div><button ng-click="login($event)" type="submit">Login</button></div>
```

*factory*

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.factory('User', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        login: function(username, password) {
        // return $http({method:'post', url: 'http://localhost:8080/CashInRestServices_war/rest/user/login', username: username, password: password})
            var data = {username: username,password: password};
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            return $http({
                method:'post', 
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/CashInRestServices_war/rest/user/login',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

*controller*

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {

    $scope.username = "viewer";
    $scope.password = "viewer";

    $scope.login = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        User.login($scope.username ,$scope.password)
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.status = response.status;
                $scope.data = response.data;
                alert(JSON.stringify({data: response.data}));
        }, function (response) { 
                $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
                $scope.status = response.status;
                alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: response.data}));
        })
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

$http service is already returning a promise, so return it directly without using all the plumber :

```
login: function(username, password) {
       return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/CashInRestServices_war/rest/user/login', {username: username, password: username});

        }   
    }
```

Comment: Thank you benek for your answer. I did tried that before but it responses null. I tried it now again but still nothing.

Comment: So it is not a problem of JS code, does your service return something in chrome/FF dev tool network panel ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, anyway if you can show us your console log.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

        .factory('User', ['$http', function($http) {

            return {
                login: function(username, password) {
                    var myUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/CashInRestServices_war/rest/user/login';

                    var data = {
                        username: username,
                        password: password
                    };

                    return $http({
                        url: myUrl,
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        headers: {
                             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        }
                      }).then(function(response) {
                           return response;
                      });
                }   
            }
        }])
```

Change your controller like this:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {

    $scope.username = "viewer";
    $scope.password = "viewer";

    $scope.login = login;

    ////////////////////
    function login() {
        User.login($scope.username ,$scope.password)
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.status = response.status;
                $scope.data = response.data;
                $scope.username = response.data.username; // I dont know if response.data.username exists but i am sure that response.username doesn't
            }
    };
}])
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan for answering, I tried your way but now it says `response = Object {data: "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Stric…rver Open Source Edition 4.1 </h3></body></html>", status: 400, config: Ob` I think it does not understand the call

Comment: I did but the problem consists. `POST http://localhost:8080/CashInRestServices_war/rest/user/login 415 (Unsupported Media Type)`
the log you asked for `data = Object {username: "viewer", password: "viewer"}`

Comment: Did you inject $httpParamSerializer? You are loging data instead ($httpParamSerializer(data)) i think

Comment: Did you mean this `$httpParamSerializer(data)
"password=viewer&username=viewer"` ?

Comment: How is your server call implement? 
Have you documentation about that? 
Do you know if you need send the user and password securized? 
And if you need send the user and password like parameters or like headers?

Comment: The service returns a JASON object. I checked it with postman (chrome's plugin) where I wrote `{"username":"viewer","password":"viewer"}` and responds with `"loginCheck": true,
  "username": "viewer"`
Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: Ohh i supuse then that your server is waiting json format parameters, i updated the answer. :)

Comment: I tested it but it returns `"data":null`. The `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` returns `{"username":"viewer","password":"viewer"}` which is the correct one. Your code seems to be correct, but for some reason it does not work. :(
 Is it cause the call is asychronous?

Comment: I dont think so, all http calls are asynchronous and they return promise. If you could get a right response with postman your problem must be some minor error. I always do it like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work either. 
Have you seen my edit above? This code responds but returns `loginCheck:false`

Comment: i figured out what is wrong. if I commented the `$scope.login = function()` it works perfectly! The problem is in the button function, but i don't have any idea why it's doing this.